# how to edit number of characters to be shown in "readmorecontrol" module?

Tags: 6

Any idea on how to edit the number of characters to be shown before the "Read More" link is displayed?

I remember this to be an editable field but not able to locate anymore how to do so.

Link to module: http://drupal.org/project/readmorecontrol

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This setting is unique for ech content type

- Select "Structure" - "Content types"
- Select "Manage display" for desired content type
- In secondary tabs select "Teaser" link
- For Content field you will something like this "Trim length: 600" - click on gear icon and change it